# No vertices after applying skin modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, vertices

I am completely new to blender and I was looking for the tools I could use to practice basic models then I applied my first modifier (skin) to the vertices I made to create a tree trunk, but unlike in the video I looked at, new vertices on the edges didnt appear and I cannot unwrap the mesh. I have seen another question exactly like mine but they went into a private conversation
[image: my tree with no vertices on edges]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You need to apply the modifier to access the modified geometry

Comment: This may be a bit confusing, but "applying a modifier" in Blender does not mean to just put it on the object. It means after you are happy with the settings and you are sure you don't want to change it anymore, you can apply the modifier meaning to create a new mesh based on the modifier's settings, and after that the modifier is removed from the object and you cannot change it anymore. There is an _Apply_ option in the modifier's menu or you could use the short Ctrl+A while hovering your mouse over the modifier.